# I want to create spinner centered in the toolbar and the dropdown arrow should sit next to the spinner text

Tags: android, spinner, android-spinner

I want to create spinner centred in the toolbar and the dropdown arrow should sit next to the spinner text.

While using gravity as centre in layout, only text is centred.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/fragment_abc"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:spinnerMode="dropdown"
    android:theme="@style/ColorControlWhite"
android:entries="@array/names"

    android:gravity="center_horizontal"



android:prompt="@string/prompt" />
```

Answer (score 2):

I know it's tooooooooo late, but I am trying to implement this now, so I want to put my solution here, if it could help some one, then good; if not, pls let me know how to make better.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/tool_bar_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
        app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:gravity="center">

            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/spinner_address_name"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                android:spinnerStyle="@android:style/Widget.Spinner.DropDown">

            </Spinner>

        </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Comment: It centered the text but the actual Spinner (exposed by placing a border around it in the LinearLayout (or RelativeLayout ... tried both) exposes that the Spinner occupies the entire toolbar. I tried combinations of wrap_content and it did not solve the problems. Arbitrary margins did not either.